# Cannot use my wifi card on windows 7, but I can on debian GNU/Linux & windows xp

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

As the title says, I can't use my wireless us robotics card on my laptop. The device managers says "This device cannot find free resources that it can use, code 12". [image: Here's a image from Device manager]

After searching a little bit on google, this type of error means that some devices are using the same I/O ports, but I have only the wifi card, and a USB mouse connected to the laptop, nothing else. I also tried to uninstall and install the drivers again, but that didn't helped. I still couldn't use the wifi card

But, if I boot on windows xp, or debian 10 buster, the wifi card will start to blink, which means that it's turned on, and I can successfully connect to the wifi, and I can browse the internet, on both, windows xp & debian OSes. Except windows 7. The card won't turn on, nothing happens. Windows 7 can also detect the wifi card, it just won't turn on/work.

Anyone knows what's wrong? What should I try? Maybe it's incompatible for windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Some drivers are OS-specific (found that out the hard way). A driver that works on WinXP or Debian won't necessarily work on Windows 7. I would use Windows XP to download the Windows 7 version of your driver to your C drive. Next, use Device Manager to select `Update Drivers` for the wifi card. Manually set the location to the directory the driver is in.

How I know this:
I once formatted my Driver partition to install Windows 8, immediately destroying a lot of stuff. I had to find Windows 8-compatible drivers before it worked. Eventually, I updated to Windows 10 and put my Win10 Compatible drivers in the software. Note: I used my USB and other devices to download said drivers.

EDIT: I was going to contain this in the answer a while ago. I noticed the Modem in the list, and dial-up modems are deprecated. If that's just a random modem driver, disabling it could give the computer the resources it needs for networking with your card.

Comment: Neither Windows XP or 7 (respectively the 2nd and the 1st most pwned OSes in history) should be used for ANY online activity even so apparently innocent and quick as what you suggest. The only sane answer is don't use any unsupported Windows, period. Use Windows 10 or Linux, end of story.

Comment: ChanganAuto, I wish I could use windows 10, but I can't, so I have to use windows 7. And the reason I want to use windows 7 is because some apps are not supported on Linux, and I don't want to use WINE, cause it's pain for me. And about the wifi drivers issue, I can just use my phone to share internet to my laptop (USB tethering), or I could get a lan cable

Comment: @dev64 [Here](https://www.driverscape.com/download/u.s.-robotics-wireless-maxg-pc-card) is the driver download for Windows 7.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Please provide evidence that using Window 7 is illegal as you claim. There is no expiry date on my Windows 7 EULA.

Comment: @DavidPostill #8 - *The software is licensed, not sold. This agreement only gives you some rights to use the features included in the software edition you licensed. Microsoft reserves all other rights.* The precedent #4 *Unless the software is
activated, you have no right to use the software* an #5 points to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/about-genuine-windows-0b88ba3d-f799-7c15-9f36-2be445a56493 which in turn leads to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-end-of-life-support-information?ocid=ocid=smc_marvel_ups_support_MoveToWindows10 (...)

Comment: (...) where is explicitly say the support has ended. Given the installation media is no longer available by any means nor means of activation provided the license is understood to be revoked by the owner of the software and thus *de facto* not legal to be used because the authorization of use is absent on the absence of all or part of the underpinnings supporting it.

Comment: M'boy, that further supports DavidPostill's and my claim. The **website you sent** says "While you could continue to use your PC running Windows 7[...]" It never says anything about it being illegal. **You just disproved yourself.**

Comment: By your own logic, the computers in federal United States departments are illegal because they run Windows 7.

Comment: @ChanganAuto "Using and unsupported OS online is dangerous". I don't really need to use it offline, mostly offline usage for a specific app. "...irresponsible and illegal". So, this means that every single school that uses windows xp or windows 7 is illegal? If so, why are they using them? "You were offered an upgrade to Windows 10...". I already told you that I can't. Because of the hardware. I managed to boot till the windows logo, and then the laptop crashed and rebooted

Comment: @WG481, I have already installed them. I just **can't use the card**. "__This device cannot find free resources that it can use, code 12__"

Comment: @dev64 Yes, in a way they are indeed. The danger is somehow mitigated in corporate environments when operated behind a network structure that has a lot a safety measures in place. It's very different with home users with such a cavalier attitude towards security that more often than not have to rely on an old an unpatched home router. XP and 7 are actually what allows bypassing that flimsy router firewall and get access to the whole LAN and then wreck havoc there and somewhere else. Who do you think are the zombie army doing all sorts of frauds and DDOS attacks? Exactly, computers like yours.

Comment: @dev64 https://healthitsecurity.com/news/fbi-operating-windows-7-increases-cyber-risk-to-network-infrastructure Note the date, August 5th 2020. Risks increase by the day. And this is what happens in the real world: https://www.securityweek.com/us-gov-warning-water-supply-hack-get-rid-windows-7

Comment: @ChanganAuto I understand, but I don't intend to use windows 7 **for online usage**. Only offline. But thank you for trying to help me, and for the links you sent

Comment: @dev64. Uninstall the driver before reinstalling. Unless of course, you already did that.

Comment: @ChanganAuto. I, like many others, know how to take care of a computer. Automatically assuming people wouldn't, saying their computer is the type used for DDoS attacks is **kind of a low shot**. Several of these administrative computers still running Windows 7 Enterprise are under **contractual agreements to receive support**. This means they get special features, while **mainstream support has ended**. The thing about licensing has already been disproved through my contact with Microsoft's Buying and Licensing help. Please discontinue the spread of disinformation.

Comment: @WG481 I've already reinstalled the drivers a million of times. I just can't get the card to work. I get the error attached on the screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOvFn.png)

Comment: @dev64 Just a point out. It looks like you have a modem in your list of drivers. If you don't need that, uninstall the modem driver. After double-checking, Code 12 means it needs more resources, and disabling/uninstalling an unnecessary modem driver could work.

Comment: @WG481 hmm alright. I'll try to disable any modems (if it does have) and I'll see